# How to combine PDF documents from Windows Explorer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer I would like to select 2 or more PDFs, right click, and choose an option which will merge the selected PDFs.

The end result should be the creation of a PDF file which combines the PDFs I selected.

How can I do this? (Or something like this, where I don't have to leave Windows Explorer).

Comment: What PDF authoring software do you have? Acrobat? What have you tried already?

Comment: I don't have any PDF authoring software. I only have PDF Sam and I didn't see an option from Windows Explorer.

Comment: One way of doing this would be compiling a tiny latex document consisting of `\includepdf{A.pdf} \includepdf{B.pdf}` and some preamble. You could both generate and compile that latex file with a tiny python script, and then adding it to the context menu shouldn't be too hard

Answer (score 2):

PDF Sam works great.  Like most free and open source software... pay very close attention to the installation as it will try to bundle crap with it.

http://www.pdfsam.org/

Comment: Not really an answer to the question.  The OP mentions in a comment already having this and it not having the desired feature, so just mentioning this product isn't a solution.

Comment: PDF Sam is a bit slow, but it's probably the best free tool to merge pdf files

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of its cost but PDF-ShellTools looks promising.

http://www.rttsoftware.com/shelltools.html

The document merging process looks like similar applications I've used and (for good reason) doesn't give you instant "merge" for multiple documents. Why? Because of requirements like "how many documents to merge at any one time" or "I want to merge certain pages from document A with document B and spend all those pages to the end of document C" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Adolix sort of works. You can send it to merge from Windows Explorer but need to go into the program to complete the task. Still faster than fully opening the documents in other merge programs.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The question asks how to do it.  This mentions a product and gives a little flavor, but doesn't explain how to accomplish the solution.  Can you add a link to the product and some explanation?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Free PDF Creator it also merges files form Windows Explorer menu https://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/download